# How do I use the ShinyRed WPF style?

Tags: wpf, xaml, themes

This is my first serious WPF application. So far there's nothing but a label on the main form.

I got the ShinyRed.xaml theme from [here](http://wpf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WPF%20Themes). I followed the instructions on the site (and on several other sites) but could not get the theme to apply to the Label control.

How do I get this style to work? Am I right in my understanding - that I can point to this style xaml and it will automatically be applied as the default style for all controls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Styles are always applied by default if they are specified as a resource using a `TargetType`. If they are placed in the Application.Resources however they will apply even inside Templates which is not the case otherwise. To use a theme you can just reference it in `App.xaml`:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/ShinyRed.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <!-- Other app resources here -->
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

See the [Resouces Overview on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750613.aspx) for more info.

Comment: This is what I did first - my label has become invisible. I think perhaps the text has inherited the colour (white) but the grid that contains the label is still white.

Comment: I've posted the fix I found on the WPFThemes page at the bottom of your answer.